# How to apply an active state to links by checking a series of urls

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unfortunately I'm not able to use the CMS to output categories for a menu item and must hard code them because my client needs to them to appear in a particular order. The CMS has no index or order attached to a particular category.

Here's my HTML:

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="/projects/" class=" active">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects/?category=discovery" class="">discovery</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects/?category=strategy" class="">strategy</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects/?category=program+design" class="">program design</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects/?category=implementation" class="">implementation</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects/?category=creative" class="">creative</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects/?category=evaluation" class="">evaluation</a></li>
</ul>
```

Question:

1. How can I make an array with the href values of every

   ?

   How can I take that array and check the browsers url to see it if matches one of those arrays, and if so, find the

   with that same href and apply an active class?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $( "a" ).each(function() {
          var url = window.location.href; 

          if($(this).attr('href') == $.trim(url))
          {
              $(this).addClass('active');
          }
          else
          {
              $(this).removeClass('active');
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var link = window.location.href.match(/category\=.+/);

if (link)
{
   $('a[href$="'+link[0]+'"]').addClass('active');
}
```

Or you can also do it this way:

```
 $('a[href$="'+window.location.search+'"]').addClass('active');
```